# ¿Se puede montar dos servidores web distintos en un mismo equipo?

Tags: php, servidor, xampp, go, windows-server

lo que intento hacer es tener dos servidores web, ambos montados en windows server. para poder consultar un api en el servidor de go , es decir, tengo un sitio en php (XAMPP) el cual lo tengo en el puerto 80 ([www.dominio.com:80](http://www.dominio.com:80)) y el segundo servidor lo estoy montando en golang y lo quiero en el puerto 8080 ([www.dominio.com:8080](http://www.dominio.com:8080)). de forma local funciona pero al intentar acceder desde otros equipos no responde, ya abri los puertos y no funciono, intente configurarlo con iis pero no lo logre.

Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes montar tantos servidores de cualquier tipo como te parezca en un mismo equipo. La única restricción es que en ese equipo, cada puerto TCP/IP sólo puede ser tomado por una aplicación o servidor en particular.

Entonces, si tienes un servidor web Apache escuchando en la puerta 80 y deseas agregar flask (para pruebas, por ejemplo), debes hacerlo en otra puerta cualquiera.

Lo mismo vale para otros servicios (bases de datos, mqtt, etc.)

Si cambiar la puerta no es conveniente, puedes optar por usar la misma puerta pero con distintas direcciones IP. Lo que haces es definir múltiples IP para la misma tarjeta, y poner un servidor en cada par IP:puerta distinto.